# Merging differnent templates into one Generic template

Tags: xslt

I have a input file

Main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Employees>
<Employee>
<id name="id">1</id>
<firstname >ABC</firstname>
<lastname >XYZ</lastname>
<age >32</age>
</Employee>
</Employees>
```

and 2 Lookup files:

Lookup1.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <Employees>
  <Employee id="1">
   <department code="102">HR</department>
  </Employee>
  </Employees>
```

Lookup2.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <Employees>
     <Employee id="1">
     <Country code="10">Canada</Country>
     </Employee>
  </Employees>
```

I want a ouput insuch a way that I passed a comma seprated values to scripts e.g "Country,Department" and it should generate the following output

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
   <Employees>
   <Employee>
    <id name="id">1</id>
    <firstname >ABC</firstname>
    <lastname >XYZ</lastname>
    <age >32</age>
    <va-object>
    <va-metadata>
     <related-content-ref area="decisions"
        cite="102"
        relationship="department" relevance="100"/>
     <primary-class>
      <super-class super-class="value-add"/>
      <sub-class sub-class="department">HR</sub-class>
    </primary-class>
  </va-metadata>
</va-object>
<va-object>
  <va-metadata>
    <related-content-ref area="decisions"
        cite="10"
        relationship="country" relevance="100"/>
    <primary-class>
      <super-class super-class="value-add"/>
      <sub-class sub-class="country">Canada</sub-class>
    </primary-class>
  </va-metadata>
</va-object>
   </Employee>
   </Employees>
```

But if I just Pass "Country" as parameter then script should not insert Department or vice-versa.I can achive this by having 2 different tempaltes country and department but i want this to be achived by using one generic template with parametes from an external file. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I suggest you reduce this to a minimum set of valid xsl that demonstrates what you want to achieve, and provide sample XML input and output.  Nobody's going to try to understand 100 lines of complex xsl with no XML context.

Comment: @atif: Your final goal can be achieved but not in the way you want to. As @Jim Garrison suggest, provide input sample and a more simple stylesheet fragment.

Comment: Thanks Guys, I will convert into simple format, but quickly can you tell me if we can pick the "xpath expression" from an external file while assigning the variable values?

Comment: You forgot to provide the full stylesheet (as minimal as possible, please) and the XML document on which to perform the transformation.

Comment: Hi Guys, just updated the question with sample input and output. Thanks

Comment: @atif: Now it's well defined. Check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:key name="kElemByParentId" match="Employee/*" use="../@id"/>
    <xsl:param name="pNames" select="'Country department'"/>
    <xsl:variable name="vNames" select="concat(' ',$pNames,' ')"/>
    <xsl:variable name="vLookup" select="document('Lookup1.xml')|
                                         document('Lookup2.xml')"/>
    <xsl:variable name="vUpper" select="'QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM'"/>
    <xsl:variable name="vLower" select="'qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm'"/>
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*" name="identity">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Employee/*[last()]">
        <xsl:variable name="vKey" select="../id"/>
        <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="$vLookup">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="key('kElemByParentId',$vKey)
                                          [contains($vNames,
                                                    concat(' ',name(),' '))]"
                                 mode="va-object"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="*" mode="va-object">
        <xsl:variable name="vName"
                      select="translate(name(),$vUpper,$vLower)"/>
        <va-object>
            <va-metadata>
                <related-content-ref area="decisions"
                                     cite="{@code}"
                                     relationship="{$vName}"
                                     relevance="100"/>
                <primary-class>
                    <super-class super-class="value-add"/>
                    <sub-class sub-class="{$vName}">
                        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                    </sub-class>
                </primary-class>
            </va-metadata>
        </va-object>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<Employees>
    <Employee>
        <id name="id">1</id>
        <firstname>ABC</firstname>
        <lastname>XYZ</lastname>
        <age>32</age>
        <va-object>
            <va-metadata>
                <related-content-ref area="decisions"
                                     cite="102"
                                     relationship="department"
                                     relevance="100" />
                <primary-class>
                    <super-class super-class="value-add" />
                    <sub-class sub-class="department">HR</sub-class>
                </primary-class>
            </va-metadata>
        </va-object>
        <va-object>
            <va-metadata>
                <related-content-ref area="decisions"
                                     cite="10"
                                     relationship="country"
                                     relevance="100" />
                <primary-class>
                    <super-class super-class="value-add" />
                    <sub-class sub-class="country">Canada</sub-class>
                </primary-class>
            </va-metadata>
        </va-object>
    </Employee>
</Employees>
```

**Note**: "Is in sequence" XPath 1.0 test:

```
contains(concat($separator,$sequence,$separator),
         concat($separator,$item,$separator))
```